# How to use Python's Easygui module to pick files and insert filenames into code

Tags: python, file, easygui

I'm trying to use Python's easygui module to select a file and then insert it's name into a program I wrote (see code below).  So I want to insert filename 1 and 2 where it says **insert filename1**, etc.. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import easygui
import csv

msg='none'
title='select a 90m distance csv file'
filetypes=['*.csv']
default='*'

filename1= easygui.fileopenbox()
filename2= easygui.fileopenbox()

dist90m_GIS_filename=(open('**insert filename1'**,'rb'))
datafile_filename=(open(**insert filename2'**,'rb'))

GIS_FH=csv.reader(dist90m_GIS_filename)
DF_FH=csv.reader(datafile_filename)

dist90m=[]
for line in GIS_FH:
    dist90m.append(line[3])

data1=[]
data2=[]
for line in DF_FH:
    data1.append(','.join(line[0:57]))
    data2.append(','.join(line[58:63]))

outfile=(open('X:\\herring_schools\\python_tests\\excel_test_out.csv','w'))
i=0
for row in data1:
    row=row+','+dist90m[i]+','+data2[i]+'\n'
    outfile.write(row)
    i=i+1
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're new to programming. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

In your code, after the lines:

```
filename1 = easygui.fileopenbox()
filename2 = easygui.fileopenbox()
```

The selected file names are stored in the variables `filename1` and `filename2`. You can use those variables to open file *handles* like this:

```
dist90m_GIS_filename=(open(filename1,'rb'))
datafile_filename=(open(filename2,'rb'))
```

Notice how I simply wrote `filename1` where you wrote `**insert filename1**`. This is the whole point of variables. You use them where you need their value.